# How to customize Jackson in Spring MVC (not Spring Boot) application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson, jackson-databind

Spring MVC 4.3.29 and Java 8 (current platform constraints), and mostly XML configuration, except for some Controller classes that are annotation-scanned.

In short, I want to get the `ObjectMapper` instance being used automatically by Spring JSON deserialization, and I want to set its `FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` back to `true`.

I see [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43120292/how-do-i-throw-a-error-on-unknown-fields-in-json-request-to-spring-restapi/52099877) [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42874369/spring-boot-1-4-customize-internal-jackson-deserialization) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30060006/how-do-i-obtain-the-jackson-objectmapper-in-use-by-spring-4-1), but all the examples seem to be [Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper) and/or Java configuration. And none of the suggested `@Autowired` beans (Mapper, Builder, etc.) have any values at all in my WebSphere environment.

Hopefully I'm just missing some simple glue somewhere.

Edit: Bah, I thought I had it with this:

```java
@Configuration
public class CustomWebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

        for (HttpMessageConverter<?> converter : converters) {
            if (converter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
                ((MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) converter).getObjectMapper().
                    enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And with my debugger I can see that it is being hit and changing the expected flag. But when used, the behavior is not in effect. I no longer have any XML overrides in place, but I do still have the "master" `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` there. I wonder if those are confusing each other...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, yes, this works as long as it's combined with `@EnableWebMvc` rather than `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`:

```java
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class CustomWebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

        for (HttpMessageConverter<?> converter : converters) {
            if (converter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
                ((MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) converter).getObjectMapper().
                    enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated, use/implement the interface `WebMvcConfigurer` instead which proviedes hooks for the different configuration steps.

Answer (score 0):

This kind-of "works", but by completely replacing Spring's `ObjectMapper`, Which then loses any other customizations it has, which I really don't want to do.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37184105/796761):

```
<bean id="myObjectMapper" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="myObjectMapper"/>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

And then I *could* `@Autowired` inject those objects and mess with them, but in this case I wouldn't need to because just a new default Jackson `ObjectMapper` actually restores the behavior I'm wanting.