# Swagger and Spring MVC (non-spring-boot)

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp, swagger-ui, web.xml, springfox

I've been trying to add Springfox-Swagger UI 3.0.0 into a regular Spring MVC application with Spring Security (non-spring-boot) and cannot figure it out. I recently incorporated swagger-ui into 2 spring-boot projects which were much easier without any issue.

I've followed numerous tutorials for this and none of them are working.

The latest tutorial I followed is the official one by [SpringFox](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#getting-started)
I also followed the demo projects from
https://github.com/springfox/springfox-demos
and more specifically the [spring-xml-swagger demo](https://github.com/springfox/springfox-demos/tree/master/spring-xml-swagger)

Requests for /swagger-ui/,/swagger-ui/index.html, /swagger-ui.html and /v2/api-docs/ return 404.

I've also tried with older versions of swagger-ui but none of them worked.
Since it's a company project I can't reveal too much but any suggestions would be nice.
I'll try to update this post with some configuration code if necessary.

Dependencies from pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Spring Framework is 5.2.x

My SwaggerConfig.class.

```java
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableWebMvc
public class SwaggerConfig {
        @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }
        private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("Api Services")
                .description("Api Services")
                .version("v1")
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public UiConfiguration uiConfiguration() {
        return UiConfigurationBuilder
                .builder()
                .defaultModelsExpandDepth(-1)
                .build();
    }
}
```

From the xml config.

```xml
    <mvc:resources mapping="/swagger-ui/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/"/>
    <mvc:view-controller path="/swagger-ui/" view-name="forward:/swagger-ui/index.html"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="index.html" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/"/>
    <bean id="swaggerConfig" class="com.example.config.SwaggerConfig"/>
```

Comment: This can work. I'm looking for relevant differences in a working instance I have...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

For anyone interested, it turns out that I needed to configure Servlet configuration through web.xml since our current servlet was configured with
`<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>` and that was blocking me from accessing the swagger related URLs.

The configuration which solved my issue is the following.

> web.xml

```xml
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>swagger-ui</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:/swagger-servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>swagger-ui</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/swagger-ui/index.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/swagger-ui/springfox.css</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/swagger-ui/swagger-ui.css</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/swagger-ui/springfox.js</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/swagger-ui/swagger-ui.js</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/swagger-ui/swagger-ui-bundle.js</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/swagger-ui/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/swagger-ui/favicon-32x32.png</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/swagger-ui/favicon-16x16.png</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/swagger-resources/configuration/ui</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/swagger-resources/configuration/security</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/swagger-resources</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/v2/api-docs</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

> swagger-servlet-context.xml

```xml
    <context:component-scan base-package="my.app.path.config, my.app.path.web.controllers" />
    
    <!-- cache resources to the browser-->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/swagger-ui/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/"/>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/swagger-ui/**" />
        <mvc:mapping path="/v2/api-docs/**" />
        </mvc:interceptor>
    </mvc:interceptors>
    
    <!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm not saying this with certainty, but [in my experience at least some aspects of Spring MVC seem to be unhappy with a mix of XML and Annotation-based configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64289359/796761). In particular, `@EnableWebMvc`.

In any case, our working app, with Spring 5.3.x and SpringFox 3.0, we did some additional things in our `@EnableSwagger2` class, including what is specified here:

http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#changes-in-swagger-ui

> For non-boot applications springfox-swagger-ui is no longer automatically enabled by adding the dependency. It needs to be explicitly register using a resource handler configurer (WebFluxConfigurer or WebMvcConfigurer).

With this example copied from that page, which must be where I got it earlier:

```java
public class SwaggerUiWebMvcConfigurer implements WebMvcConfigurer {
  private final String baseUrl;

  public SwaggerUiWebMvcConfigurer(String baseUrl) {
    this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
  }

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    String baseUrl = StringUtils.trimTrailingCharacter(this.baseUrl, '/');
    registry.
        addResourceHandler(baseUrl + "/swagger-ui/**")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/")
        .resourceChain(false);
  }

  @Override
  public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController(baseUrl + "/swagger-ui/")
        .setViewName("forward:" + baseUrl + "/swagger-ui/index.html");
  }
}
```

So, while your XML configuration would seem to be duplicating that, *maybe* that has to be in Annotation configuration instead, if using `@EnableWebMvc`.

And/or, it might be that in order to use `@Bean` in your class, you also have to have `@Configuration` on the class as well. That's another difference in our setup.

My Spring and SpringFox `pom.xml` excerpts:

```xml
...
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>

        <spring.version>5.3.30</spring.version>
        <springfox.version>3.0.0</springfox.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
...
```

Our config class has these annotations:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSwagger2
@Import(springfox.bean.validators.configuration.BeanValidatorPluginsConfiguration.class)
public class SpringFoxConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
```

(The last one is specifically for [JSR-303 validation awareness](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#springfox-support-for-jsr-303); it should not be required for basic operation.)

And, finally, I think the only relevant part of our single Spring XML configuration file, which is loaded from our `web.xml` file via `DispatcherServlet`:

```xml
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <bean class="our.app.package.api.swagger.SpringFoxConfig"/>
```

Other potentially-relevant differences from your example:

- we don't have any custom `UiConfiguration` bean
- we use a custom/limited path selector in our `Docket` builder: `.apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("our.app.package"))`

(I'd be surprised if the latter made a difference.)

Finally, at application start, do you see an entry like this in your server log? (If debug logging is enabled.)

> 12:17:51,960 DEBUG _org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping.Mappings:'resourceHandlerMapping' {/swagger-ui/**=ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/]]}

Sorry I can't give a more expert, certain answer, but maybe this at least helps. I can at least confirm non-boot SpringMVC with SpringFox can/does work.

Comment: Thank you @dbreaux for your prompt answer. I've tried this and also moved the mvc:annotations xml config to the class with annotations EnableWebMvc & Configuration. Still not working. Since it's working for you could you please provide me with some more information regarding your solution? Such as the dependencies for swagger you used and some part of your Swagger configuration class.

Comment: Thank you for your updates @dbreaux. Stil no solution for my issue.  Do you use JSP on your project?  Did you use any dependencies for spring-boot or webjars?
How is your WebMvcConfigurer implemented?

Comment: No Spring Boot or JSPs in this application. Almost the entire WebMvcConfigurer class is above, but I'll see if anything missing that could matter...